# Си. Взаимосвязь графики и логики игры

Tags: c, winapi

Хочу написать игру Pacman с помощью Win API (язык строго Си). Вообще это моя первая игра такого рода (должна быть), не хотелось бы ее забросить. Как организовать взаимодействие графики и логики? Например, игровое поле делится на клетки, условно говоря, в каждой может храниться либо белая точка, либо кусок стены, да еще по центру карты комнатка с приведениями. Поле, как я грубо посчитал, состоит из 31х27 клеток. Допустим, логика будет оперировать с матрицей, а вот что насчет графики? Там же все в координатах.

Если есть более удобная граф. библиотека, жду предложений, Win API не обязательно использовать.

Comment: Почитайте про MVC, например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из возможных вариантов.

Можно разделить представление на две составляющие - непосредственно саму карту с неподвижными объектами (стенами) и на подвижные объекты (герой, враги).

Например, для карты размером 32*24 блока и с размером одного блока 32*32 пикселя, размер общей карты будет 1024*768 пикселей.

Сами блоки хранятся в виде массива байтов и каждый байт означает какой-то блок стены (например, 0 - вертикальная стена, 1 - горизонтальная стена, 2 - левый верхний угол и т.д). При рисовании такого массива на экран для преобразования координат достаточно просто умножать на размер изображения одного блока. Для размеров, кратных степени двойки (как упомянутые выше 32*32), это можно делать с помощью побитовых сдвигов. Вся работа с блоками ведётся именно через массив. Координаты блоков вышеупомянутой карты будут заданы в диапазоне от 0 до 31 по горизонтали и от 0 до 23 по вертикали. Сам массив будет одномерным и двухмерные координаты в линейную адресацию и обратно будут преобразовываться "на лету" с помощью простейших функций. Например, `index = y * map_width + x;`

Также нужно будет написать функцию проверки наличия блока с преобразованием координат из пространства пикселей в пространство массива. Это нужно для организации проверки столкновений подвижных объектов со стенами. Самый простой способ - делать проверку по ограничивающему прямоугольнику. Для этого достаточно проверить, есть ли столкновение каждого из четырёх углов с блоком в массиве.

Если говорить конкретно о Pacman, то там можно сделать более простую проверку, которая будет смотреть наличие блока, без проверки ограничивающего прямоугольника. Это связано с тем, что Pacman двигается исключительно по клеткам (плавно перемещаясь между ними) и когда он выравнивается по центру клетки, в этот момент делается проверка пользовательского ввода и наличие препятствий на пути.

При этом можно определить диапазоны, какие объекты в карте являются "твёрдыми" (то есть стенами), а какие не ограничивают движение (в случае Pacman, например, это могут быть маленькие точки, большие точки и стартовые позиции героя и врагов).

Подвижные же объекты хранятся в виде списка и у каждого из них есть свои координаты на экране (в пикселях). Они работают именно в этом пространстве. Столкновения между собой, в простейшем случае, делаются перебором списка и (при использовании bounding box) простыми проверками каждой грани ограничивающего прямоугольника, либо, как вариант - проверкой расстояния между объектами, что в случае Pacman вполне может подойти.

Сам игровой процесс обычно представлен примерно так:

- Input (пользовательский ввод)
- Update (шаг игры)
- Draw (рисование)

В вашем случае, рисование будет разделено на две части:

- Рисование карты (как стены, так и точки)
- Рисование подвижных объектов (перемещающихся бонусов, врагов и героя)

Что касается движков/фреймворков/библиотек/инструментария, то это очень индивидуально, но всё же немного напишу об этом.

Простые карты для Pacman можно создавать сразу в массиве, но для более сложных карт/игр лучше пользоваться визуальными редакторами, например [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org), который имеет [поддержку](http://doc.mapeditor.org/reference/support-for-tmx-maps/) для множества языков и движков/фреймворков.

Также вы можете воспользоваться каким-нибудь готовым движком/специализированным фреймворком (достаточно простым, например, является Allegro http://alleg.sourceforge.net - к нему есть биндинги на различные языки, в том числе - Си; подойдёт для новичков) или легким фреймворком ([SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org/index.php) например). В первом случае нужно будет писать меньше, во втором - больше, а под Win API - ещё больше.

Я бы рекомендовал для начала воспользоваться каким-нибудь движком, чтобы просто получить представление о том, "как это примерно может быть" и только после этого переходить на легковесные фреймворки (если есть такая необходимость). А для самой первой игры я бы вообще рекомендовал использовать какой-нибудь конструктор, например, [Game Maker Studio](http://yoyogames.com) - хотя это и не Си (однако, язык GML позволяет писать в схожем стиле и используя синтаксис Си; и, конечно же, речь идёт об использовании только GML, не используя программирования "кнопками", предназначенными для тех, кто программированием никогда не занимался), но это позволило бы сначала получить представление о том, что вообще может быть внутри игры - какие события, какие функции, способы взаимодействия объектов и т.п.

P.S. Вы знаете, что поведение приведений в оригинальном Pacman несколько более сложное, чем кажется на первый взгляд? На русском языке об этом можно почитать [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/109406/).

Comment: Разумеется, в вики было подробно описан ИИ приведений. А вот ответ очень подробен. Я, например, не додумался для каждого отдельного вида блока вывести отдельное значение (для угла - 2, для верт. стены - 3) -- это очень мне поможет, спасибо огромное. А вот насчет фреймворка... Пожалуй, посмотрю в сторону Allegro. C SDL я уже работал, там действительно кучу всего надо писать. Спасибо огромное за столь содержательный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В общем виде: координаты из игрового мира транслируются через ViewMatrix и результат проецируется на видеобуфер.